# Laptop fails to wake up after sleep for several hours

Tags: suspend, sleep

I shut the lid on my Toshiba and go to sleep. I come back in the morning and it won't wake back up. It seems like I can put it to sleep for less than 2 hours. After that, I'll have to do a hard reboot to do anything. It doesn't seem to happen If I have VLC running. Any advice?

running 12.04 w/ Gnome 3.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible modes when you put your computer to sleep:

1. Suspending aka "Suspend To RAM": Memory is kept in RAM, a small amount of power is still used, wake up time is short
2. Hibernating aka "Suspend To Disk": Memory is dumped to the harddisk, no power is used, longer wake up time

I suspect by closing the lid you put your computer into suspend mode. If it is only running  on battery, it gets drained after a while and the contents of the memory are lost, so you have to do a normal reboot.

Additional info:
https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/hardware/C/pm-suspending.html